# Kali Linux Rolling - apt-get upgrade: failed to fetch 404 not found

Tags: linux, kali-linux, apt-get

I'm trying to update my linux packages but I get the following error:

```
# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://ftp.be.debian.org/debian wheezy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.be.debian.org/debian wheezy Release
Hit:4 http://ftp2.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  cadaver cups-bsd cups-client curl empathy exim4-daemon-light gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
  gir1.2-totem-1.0 glib-networking iptables ldap-utils libavformat-ffmpeg56 libct4 libcups2
  libcupsimage2 libcurl3-gnutls libgadu3 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnustep-base1.24 libgnutls-openssl27
  libimobiledevice6 libldap-2.4-2 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra libneon27-gnutls libnm-gtk-common
  libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnm0 libopencv-calib3d2.4v5 libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-core2.4v5
  libopencv-features2d2.4v5 libopencv-flann2.4v5 libopencv-highgui2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5
  libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml2.4v5 libopencv-objdetect2.4v5 libopencv-video2.4v5
  libpython3-stdlib librtmp1 libsybdb5 libvncclient1 libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common
  libwireshark6 libzmq3 netsniff-ng network-manager network-manager-gnome ntfs-3g pack
  python-netlib python-pycurl python3 python3-minimal telepathy-gabble telepathy-salut totem
  totem-plugins tshark vino vlc vlc-nox vpnc wget wireshark-common wireshark-qt
  xserver-xorg-video-all
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gnuplot5-data gnuplot5-qt libpackagekit-glib2-18 nano packagekit
  packagekit-tools set xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-evdev
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-legacy xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xwayland
26 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
Need to get 55.1 MB/58.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 108 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 nano amd64 2.5.1-1
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpackagekit-glib2-18 amd64 1.0.11-2
  404  Not Found
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 amd64 1.0.11-2
  404  Not Found
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gnuplot5-qt amd64 5.0.2+dfsg1-2
  404  Not Found
Err:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gnuplot5-data all 5.0.2+dfsg1-2
  404  Not Found
Err:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 packagekit-tools amd64 1.0.11-2
  404  Not Found
Err:7 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 packagekit amd64 1.0.11-2
  404  Not Found
Err:8 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xserver-common all 2:1.18.0-3
  404  Not Found
Err:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xserver-xephyr amd64 2:1.18.0-3
  404  Not Found
Err:10 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xserver-xorg-legacy amd64 2:1.18.0-3
  404  Not Found
Err:11 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xserver-xorg-core amd64 2:1.18.0-3
  404  Not Found
Err:12 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 xwayland amd64 2:1.18.0-3
  404  Not Found
Err:13 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 set all 7.0.3.3-0kali1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/n/nano/nano_2.5.1-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/packagekit/libpackagekit-glib2-18_1.0.11-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/packagekit/gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0_1.0.11-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/g/gnuplot5/gnuplot5-qt_5.0.2+dfsg1-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/g/gnuplot5/gnuplot5-data_5.0.2+dfsg1-2_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/packagekit/packagekit-tools_1.0.11-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/packagekit/packagekit_1.0.11-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-common_1.18.0-3_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xephyr_1.18.0-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xorg-legacy_1.18.0-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xorg-core_1.18.0-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xwayland_1.18.0-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/s/set/set_7.0.3.3-0kali1_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried the following commands in this order but it didn't help.

- sudo apt-get clean
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get upgrade
- sudo apt-get update --fix-broken
- sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sources.list:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 2$

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 2$

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

deb http://ftp.be.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
```

Also my key list is up to date (as far as I can see).

```
# apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   4096R/1804772E 2014-11-24
uid                  Emdebian Toolchain Archive (signing key)

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/2B90D010 2014-11-21 [expires: 2022-11-19]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/C857C906 2014-11-21 [expires: 2022-11-19]
uid                  Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/518E17E1 2013-08-17 [expires: 2021-08-15]
uid                  Jessie Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg
-----------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/473041FA 2010-08-27 [expires: 2018-03-05]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg
--------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/B98321F9 2010-08-07 [expires: 2017-08-05]
uid                  Squeeze Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/46925553 2012-04-27 [expires: 2020-04-25]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/65FFB764 2012-05-08 [expires: 2019-05-07]
uid                  Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kali-archive-keyring.gpg
-----------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/7D8D0BF6 2012-03-05 [expires: 2018-02-02]
uid                  Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
sub   4096R/FC0D0DCB 2012-03-05 [expires: 2018-02-02]
```

Everything was working fine but today randomly when trying to upgrade packages it gives that error.
I can still install other software though.
Does anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: apt couldn't able to connect to repository. Check if internet is ok

Comment: @7171u My internet works. I can connect manually to the repository without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind my VPS hosting e-mailed me saying there were some problems with my VPS and that they where working on fixing it. And I just tried it and it worked again...

Very strange since I could reach the kali repository manually just fine...

Answer (score 7):

I used

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

deb-src http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

for sources instead of the original ones. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Can you point to an official source suggesting these? It looks from the URLs like they are *probably* safe to use, but given the level of compromise that can happen when using an inappropriate repository (basically, an attacker can take over the whole system), some sort of official statement -- even if it's just a page on the distro's official web site giving them as an alternative -- is always good.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That would indeed be nice since I've heard something like that is going around lately. dimitrios1988 Could you provide an official source suggesting these?

Comment: I don't have an official source. I found it on another forum.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, btw it is Kali's subdomain. Don't worry. There is no attacker. And the packages are signed by Kali.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Kali Linux Official Documentation](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories), the `sources.list` file should contain the following line(s):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

(changing/updating my `sources.list` file accordingly, fixed this issue for me)

Answer (score 3):

You could try to change your repository protocol from ***http*** to ***https*** at /etc/apt/sources.list ; this worked for me.

[image]

Then you can update or upgrade without problems

```
$ sudo apt update && apt upgrade
```

source solution: https://linuxconfig.org/kali-linux-failed-to-fetch-inrelease-repository-fix

Comment: This works, and will work for most of the people having this issue as of May 2021, this should be marked as a reply.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me
step 1.
wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc  | apt-key add

step 2.
apt install ./kali-archive-keyring_2018.1_all.deb

step 3
apt-get update

Answer (score 0):

If nothing of the above works, it is probably the network adapter problem. I use VBox and changing the adapter from NAT to Bridged Adapter solved this!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and made a video explaining how to solve it along with any missing Linux headers.
https://youtu.be/8A-scMfJDT8

You basically need to add the berkley mirror for kali
https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/kali/

You can see how to add it to the sources list in my video above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for most recent versions such as Kali 2023.1, the reason is "The great non-free firmware transition".

just change the `firmware` to `non-free-firmware` in your `/etc/apt/source.list`

or just do this
`sudo sed -i 's/non-free$/non-free non-free-firmware/' /etc/apt/sources.list`

more about the transition here,
https://www.kali.org/blog/non-free-firmware-transition/

Answer (score -1):

- Remove the sources.list file located in `/etc/apt`.
- Then, use the touch command to create a new sources.list file.
- After that, type the following command to add the repository links: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`.
- Once you execute this command, you will enter the GNU nano interface. Next, paste the following
  `link:deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free` . Press Ctrl+X, then Y, and finally Enter to save the changes.

After completing these steps, you can verify if the repo link is saved by running the command: `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Once you have followed all the instructions, run the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` to update your Linux system.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a beginner, don't know much in depth about the issue. I, though, wasted my two whole days searching on internet about same problem: "kali rolling repository is not updating." Nothing worked. Then I switched from my public hostel Wi-Fi to paid mobile internet hotspot, re-tried the following command:

```
apt-get update
```

and it worked perfectetly.
If U are using some school or public Wi-Fi, it maybe restricting or blocking your hits. Try SWITCHING your internet connections or use VPN. Worked for me.

Comment: What exactly is your suggestion?  The author already attempted `apt-get update` which is the entire reason this question exists.  The author submitted an answer themselves indicating it was a problem with their VPS service itself.

Comment: I am a beginner myself. Don't know in depth. apt-get update was not working for me on 'public Wi-Fi'. When I switched to my own internet connection , it worked. I was suggesting to switch internet connections or try a VPN!

Comment: The author is using a VPS, difficult to use a "different internet connection" in that case.  The suggestion of a VPN has some merits but seems overkill.

Answer (score -2):

deb http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

deb-src http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib